# what do all the +'s and -'s in Objective-C mean?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

in function signatures, like:

```
- (void)dealloc
```

?

thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `-` denotes an instance method, while the `+` denotes a class method that doesn't belong to a specific instance.

Comment: awesome, thanks! and if you don't have a + or a - then it's just a regular function (no associated class)?

Comment: If there's no + or -, it's not an Objective-C method (i.e, a C function).